# Multiple If Statements for a merge field for a HTML Email Template

Tags: formula, email-template, html, if, merge-field

I am trying to create a conditional formula for a merge field for a HTML Email Template with the following logic;
IF both ICMS ID and Portal ID are present then only show ICMS ID
OR
IF only ICMS ID is present show that
IF only Portal ID is present show that

I created the following formula

```
 {!IF 
     (AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c & Case.Portal_ID__c))), Case.ICMS_ID__c, ""
,
    
    !IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)), Case.ICMS_ID__c, ""
,
    
    !IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c)), Case.Portal_ID__c , ""
,
    
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong but the required information is not coming into the email template. If the field is filled out, no information is appearing.

I am not sure where I am going wrong, please help!

EDIT:
Have tried the suggestion from below and still no information is appearing

```
  {!IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)),
             NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c))), 
                             Case.ICMS_ID__c, "",  
     !IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)),
                             Case.ICMS_ID__c, "",  
     !IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c)), 
                             Case.Portal_ID__c , "",  
}
```

EDIT:
Have now also tried the below suggestion and the field on the email template is still appearing as blank even if data is entered in both ICMS ID & Portal ID or just one of them.

```
     {!IF(
        AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)), NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c))), 
            Case.ICMS_ID__c,  
            IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)),
                Case.ICMS_ID__c,  
                IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c)), 
                    Case.Portal_ID__c, 
                    ""  
                )
            )
        )

}
```

Comment: what object is this HTML Email Template's Email Alert associated with?

Comment: there is no email alert, this is being used as a manual template for cases

Answer (score 2):

Try using this formula -

```
 {!IF(
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)), NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c))), 
        Case.ICMS_ID__c,  
        IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)),
            Case.ICMS_ID__c,  
            IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c)), 
                Case.Portal_ID__c, 
                ""  
            )
        )
    )
}
```

We don't have to use exclamation marks each and every time. If using multiple exclamation signs within single pair of curly braces, those were treated as NOT logical operators.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you so much. Nothing is appearing still in the required field on the email and I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

`ISBLANK()` only accepts one field, so `ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c & Case.Portal_ID__c)` is invalid.  You need a separate ISBLANK for each field.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried your suggestion and still nothing is appearing in the email `{!IF
(AND

(NOT

(ISBLANK

(Case.ICMS_ID__c)),NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c))), Case.ICMS_ID__c, "",

!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c)), Case.ICMS_ID__c, "",

!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c)), Case.Portal_ID__c , "",

}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the final formula I came up with that satisfied all requirements. As always, the simplest answer ended up being the best.

```
{!IF
    (ISBLANK(Case.Portal_ID__c), IF(ISBLANK(Case.ICMS_ID__c), "", 
        (Case.ICMS_ID__c)), (Case.Portal_ID__c))}
```

Comment: alternative practice is to use NULL instead of `""`; avoids potential formula syntax errors